# What does django urlpattern path argument empty (' ') meaning?

Tags: python, django

what does path('') in urls.py from project mean?

This is urls.py from project.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls'))
]
```

And this is urls.py from app

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('create/', views.create),
    path('read/id/', views.read),
    ]
```

Is path('')in urls.py from project just mean empty?

If it is, why when I write localhost:8080/create

It will still work?
I just routing path('') in urls.py from project
Does it mean "except admin/" ..?

Answer (score 2):

it means that the paths below `myapp.urls` will be added *without any prefix*, so that means that the paths will be:

```
admin/    … (all admin urls)
/         → views.index
create/   → views.create
read/id/  → views.read
```

likely however the path to `read` should contain a URL parameter, not `id` in the real path, so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('create/', views.create),
    path('read/<int:id>/', views.read),
]
```

If you had added a value to the path, like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('foo/', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

then the paths would be:

```
admin/        … (all admin urls)
foo/          → views.index
foo/create/   → views.create
foo/read/id/  → views.read
```